# Running into some logical errors with my code

Tags: python

I am the given the following problem and asked to write a solution algorithm for it using python.

problem: 
Write a Python program to determine the student with the highest average.  Each student takes a midterm and a final. The grades should be validated to be between 0 and 100 inclusive. Input each student’s name and grades and calculate the student’s average. Output the name of the student with the best average and their average.

Here is my code:

```
def midTerm():
    midtermScore = int(input("What is the midterm Score: "))
    while (midtermScore <= 0 or midtermScore >= 100):
        midtermScore = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 100: "))
    return midtermScore
def final():
    finalScore = int(input("What is the final Score: "))
    while (finalScore < 0 or finalScore > 100):
        finalScore = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 100: "))
    return finalScore

total = 0
highest = 0
numStudents = int (input("How Many Students are there? "))
while numStudents < 0 or numStudents > 100:
    numStudents = int (input("Please enter a number between 0 and 100? "))
for i in range (1, numStudents+1):
    students = (input("Enter Student's Name Please: "))
    score = (midTerm()+ final())
    total += score
avg = total/numStudents
if (highest < avg):
    highest = avg
    winner = students
print ("The Student with the higgest average is: ", winner, "With the highest average of: ", avg)
```

The issue I am running into is the last part. The program does not print the name of the person with the highest average, but the name of the person that was entered at the very last. I am very confused on how to go forward from here. Can you please help? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Look at the line: `students = (input("Enter Student's Name Please: "))` - you are re-assigning it every time through the loop. You have the same assignment problem with `numStudents` as well. This would also be a good a time as any to learn to [debug python](https://pymotw.com/2/pdb/), as from a quick glance there are multiple logic errors that will end up giving you incorrect results.

Comment: You assign `winner = students`, so look at the value of students, and it is assigned `students = (input("Enter Student's Name Please: "))` you never actually assign correct student resulting in the logic error.

Comment: There may be a good question in here, but your question title is inappropriate. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: In this kind of situations, the debugger is your friend. To use pdb, execute `python -m pdb yourprogram.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far off.  Take a look here:

```
for i in range (1, numStudents+1):
    students = (input("Enter Student's Name Please: "))
    score = (midTerm()+ final())
    total += score
avg = total/numStudents
if (highest < avg):
    highest = avg
    winner = students
```

Besides the indentation error (hopefully just clumsy copy-pasting)  You're not actually calculating each student's average score anywhere.  Try something like this:

```
for i in range (numStudents):
    student_name = (input("Enter Student's Name Please: ")) 
    student_avg = (midTerm() + final()) / 2 # 2 scores, summed and divided by 2 is their average score
    if (highest < student_avg):
        highest = student_avg
        winner = student_name  # save student name for later

print ("The Student with the higgest average is: ", winner, "With the highest average of: ", highest)
```

It looks like you were originally trying to calculate the total class average, which is not what's described by the problem statement.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help solve the problem. I tried my best to answer this myself before posting, but I was left with no choice here. Of course, I am a python noob and I am still learning. Your answer was way better than some of the comments above (in fact the comments above discourage people from asking questions). Thanks again!

Comment: Sure thing, I thought the zealous downvoting was a little harsh, but SO does have standards to adhere to.  We all were noobs once, IMO a decent question with a vague title is still a decent question.  Regardless, welcome to SO!